# Twitter API application-only authentication

Tags: api, twitter-oauth

I am implementing OAuth using Twitter API following the documentation :
 [Application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only)
I created POST request using Consumer key & Consumer Secret as below :

```
POST http://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token
Authorization:  Basic T3k2TlA4SnpCVGRiNXlFTUt2dGswamJGSTpiSlpEYm1xeExyeDJKU25JbUplcWdlQTJkREcwZXg0bUNtOUdGTGJ1TGF3TkZkNkxqNg==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
grant_type=client_credentials
```

I got a responce having below error:

> "{"errors":[{"code":99,"label":"authenticity_token_error","message":"Unable to verify your credentials"}]}"

Although, I'm getting data from my app settings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I received a token with your request.

**Important!** You must invalidate the security token afterwards, **never ever** share on public resources your credentials, provide some dummy data.

Your issue is described in documentation in chapter "Invalid requests to obtain or revoke bearer tokens"

The `grant_type=client_credentials` is not a header, but the body of the request:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token \
  --header 'authorization: Basic T3k2TlA4SnpCVGRiNXlFTUt2dGswamJGSTpiSlpEYm1xeExyeDJKU25JbUplcWdlQTJkREcwZXg0bUNtOUdGTGJ1TGF3TkZkNkxqNg==' \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data grant_type=client_credentials
```

**Additional though**: maybe the issue is that you are using `http://...` URL, whereas the proper is to use `https://...` link

Answer (score 11):

Follow the 2 steps. I have done it myself & tested it also .Its working fine and you will be able to get the access token

**Step 1)**

In your case, you have to replace below two values with your consumer key & secret:

**Cosumer key** = xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog

**Consumer secret** = L8qq9PZyRg6ieKGEKhZolGC0vJWLw8iEJ88DRdyOg

using consumer key & consumer secret, we have to generate a base 64 string. So to do that, we have to first concatenate consumer key & consumer secret using colon(:) as separator

So in my case, the concatenated string will be :

```
xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog:L8qq9PZyRg6ieKGEKhZolGC0vJWLw8iEJ88DRdyOg
```

**Note:There should not be a white-space in concatenated string**

So now we are ready with our concatenated string. Now we have to generate base 64 string. For this, we can use online service to do this. 
Open this URL http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp and paste your concatenated string & click on "Convert the source code".That will give you Base 64 string.

In my case, Base 64 string is (You will have different in your case) :

**xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog:L8qq9PZyRg6ieKGEKhZolGC0vJWLw8iEJ88DRdyOg**

Now, by using our Base64 String, we have to generate Base 64 Encoded string. So to do that, we can use online service. Open the link https://www.base64encode.org/ and paste our Base64 string & Click on "Encode".

And finally you will get Base64 Encoded string which we have to use in token request.
In my case, it look like this :

**eHZ6MWV2RlM0d0VFUFRHRUZQSEJvZzpMOHFxOVBaeVJnNmllS0dFS2hab2xHQzB2SldMdzhpRUo4OERSZHlPZw==**

**Step 2)**

Now Open your POSTMAN (It is plugin for google chrome for testing API's) & do the below steps :(I am attaching screenshot of POSTMAN request as well, have a look into it if you are new to the POSTMAN)

1. The request must be a HTTP POST request. and url is : https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token
2. The request must include an Authorization header with the value of Basic .
   **for example :**

   Basic eHZ6MWV2RlM0d0VFUFRHRUZQSEJvZzpMOHFxOVBaeVJnNmllS0dFS2hab2xHQzB2SldMdzhpRUo4OERSZHlPZw==
3. The request must include a Content-Type header with the value of application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
   **for example : Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded**
4. Click on Body->Raw and type **grant_type=client_credentials**

[image]

[image]

Click on SEND, & you will get your access token.

Let me know if you face any issue while doing this steps.

Comment: did you try at your end?

Comment: yes, but the main problem was an absense "https" prefix

Comment: @ЕвгенийEvgeniy   Ohhhh yes, i should be https. Anyways It will help people to implement this without any trouble

Comment: This worked for me only when I skipped the first step (regarding https://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp). Also, here is a link to the official Twitter docs specifying exactly what this post suggests: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/application-only.html

Answer (score 2):

This Type of Format should be used in your header and twitter uses OAuth 1.0

```
Authorization:OAuth oauth_consumer_key="{consumer-key}",oauth_token="{oauth token},oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1500034490",oauth_nonce="ycnFHs",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="{oauth-signature}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some of you might have problem with generating Base64 encoded bearer token credentials (what you pass with Basic XXX in Authorization header)

Then Basic Auth (Authorization tab) can help you:

[Basic Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh92N.png)

It will automatically add proper Authorization header with value

[Authorization header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TILsA.png)

Reference: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/application-only